# Scroll won't work on Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, scroll

The scroll will not work on a few pages of my site.  I am not exactly sure why.

Here is an example of a page that does not work:

https://gmatanswers.com

While the scroll works fine here:

https://gmatanswers.com/posts

Everything seems to work fine on Firefox, it is just chrome.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.
Try to disable Smooth Scroll on about:flags
Works for me.